# How to quit TeX in interactive mode on CLI in Windows 10?

Tags: tex-core

Suppose I have a file named `demo.tex` containing:

```
\hrule
\vskip 1in
\centerline{\bf A SHORT STORY}
\vskip 6pt
\centerline{\sl by A. U. Thor}
\vskip .5cm
Once upon a time, in a distant galaxy called \"O\"o\c c, there lived a computer named R.~J. Drofnats. Mr.~Drofnats---or ‘‘R. J.,’’ as he preferred to be called---was happiest when he was at work typesetting beautiful documents.
\vskip 1in
\hrule
\vfill\eject
```

I open `cmd` on Windows 10 then excute `C:\>tex demo.tex`. Then there is a star or two stars in the next line. Knuth said that use `\relax` to quit, but it doesn't works for me. How could I quit?

By the way, could I use TeXstudio to run `demo.tex`?

Comment: You should terminate the interactive run: type in `\end` or `\bye` followed by return.

Comment: You can also press `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman That does not force-stop TeX (then you're at the interruption `?` prompt).

Comment: Pretty sure nowhere does Knuth say to use `\relax` to quit. That's just not what `\relax` does / how TeX works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should type in `\relax` at the double `**` prompt in an interactive session, because at this stage TeX is looking for a file name to input.

However, no `**` prompt will appear if you run

```
tex demo.tex
```

Here's what happens on my system (`story.tex` is the same as your `demo.tex`):

```
> tex story
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/story.tex [1])
*
```

This single `*` prompt means that TeX is waiting for material to typeset (actually, for commands to interpret). You can ask for ending the job by issuing `\end` or `\bye` (the latter is generally better, but in this case the two are equivalent).

Here's what happens when I type in `\end` followed by return

```
*\end
Output written on story.dvi (1 page, 680 bytes).
Transcript written on story.log.
```

Typing in `\relax` would order TeX to do nothing, so you get another `*` prompt.

Comment: thanks. Suggested by you, I write \end into the file and it works too. really thanks to you.